# Why is $\mathbb{N}$ with cofinite topology an US-space?

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, convergence-divergence

This website: http://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/US_not_implies_Hausdorff says that this space is an US-space. But, it seems to me that the sequence $(x_n)$ s.t. $x_n=n$, for all $n$, converges to every point in $\mathbb{N}$. And here is the proof:

Take $x\in \mathbb{N}$ and $U$ an open neighborhood of $x$. Define $m=\max( \mathbb{N}\setminus U)$, which exists, since $|\mathbb{N}\setminus U|<\infty$. Then, $x_n\in U$ for all $n>m$. It follows that $x_n\to x$. As $x$ is arbitrary we have that $(x_n)$ converges to all point in $\mathbb{N}$. What is wrong with my proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, and the example on that site is wrong.  It probably meant to give the example of an uncountable set with the cocountable topology instead.  (Exercise: show that in such a space, any convergent sequence is eventually constant.)